Howto update inventory count on nest product
I have an nested Product inventory object. However, when I increment the inventory count the value does not get incremented. Here is the object structure. The inventoryDetails count always remains 0, and no error is thrown. The updateInventory function is shown below

         import mongoose, {UpdateWriteOpResult} from "mongoose";

         interface Product {
           id: String,
           productCode: String,
           productName: String,
           inventoryDetails:{
            count: Number,
            onHandLevel: Number
         }
       }

       export const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
       {
           _id: String,
           productCode: String,
           productName: String,
           inventoryDetails:{
             count: Number,
             onHandLevel: Number
         }
     },
     {_id: false}
    )

     export interface ProductDocument extends Product, Document {
     }

     export const ProductModel = mongoose.model<ProductDocument>('product', ProductSchema)
 
     async function updateInventory(productId: string): Promise<UpdateWriteOpResult> {
       
      return  ProductModel.updateOne({ _id: productId }, { $inc: {'inventoryDetails.count': 1 }} );
                                
     }




I was not calling await in the caller
